# How can you convert quarterly data into annual data in a time series when starting on quarter 3?

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to first convert my CSV (excel) data into time series which is split into quarters but starts on quarter 3. Then, I am trying to aggregate the data into yearly as follows:

```
model_Tesla = ts(tesla_model$sales, start=c(2017,3), frequency=4)

tesla_annual=aggregate(model_Tesla, FUN=sum, nfrequency=1)
```

However, when I run it the values for the annual data are all wrong. Also, it says the new ts tesla_annual starts on 2017.5 and ends on 2020.5 when that is not true. It actually ends in 2021 quarter 4. How can I fix it? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need `ts` for a particular reason, you might find package `{lubridate}` useful. It offers a number of convenient wrappers for time and date manipulation. In your case, the following code might help along:

```
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
mutate(quarters = seq(from = ymd('2017/3/1'), 
                      to = ymd('2021/12/31'),
                      by = 'quarters')

## ymd is for year/month/day; try dmy etc.
```

Comment: Thank you! But I actually need ts because I'm working with time-series data and I would need to fit the model using that function. Would the package {lubridate} and the method above still be relevant for me?